# How do I clean up self-intersecting polygons in a spatial database?

Tags: geospatial, polygon, postgis, ogc

I have some spatial data (MapInfo files) that contains self-intersecting polygons. These cause problems in my processing, in particular I can't generate geometric unions in PostGIS. Is there an easy way to resolve the issue? I can deal with multi-polygons if that should be necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out myself: an `st_buffer(wkb_geometry,0)` does the trick, at least on my sample data.